# how make some value of a column NA with respect of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to make value of each row of column A , NA ,where column B is 2:

data

```
          A   B
          1   2 
          2   4
          NA  5
          6   2
```

output

```
          A   B
          NA   2 
          2   4
          NA  5
          NA   2
```

first and last row of B was 2 so A got NA in those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using `ifelse` in base R -

```
df$A <- ifelse(df$B == 2, NA_real_, df$A)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(A = sample(1:10, size=5, replace=T),
                 B = sample(1:10, size=5, replace=T))
df

  A B
1 9 7
2 4 2
3 7 3
4 1 1
5 2 5

df$A[df$B == 2] <- NA

df

   A B
1  9 7
2 NA 2
3  7 3
4  1 1
5  2 5
```